# Grails: Paging and Sorting over the collection in a relationship

Tags: grails, pagination, grails-orm

I'd like to do paging and sorting from a collection in a relationship

For example with the following model:

```
class User {
   String userName, password
   static hasMany = [roles: UserRole, preferences: Preference]
}

class UserRole {
   String name, description

   static hasMany = [actions: Action]
}
```

I'd like to recover all the roles for a specific user. I already have the user loaded so the normal way to do it would be using

```
user.roles
```

But I want to sort them by `UserRole` properties and I want to paginate them dynamically

I know that if I want to get all the `UserRole`s sorted and paginated I can use:

```
UserRole.list([sort: 'name', order: 'asc',max: 5,offset:0])
```

But I want to do it just for the roles that are associated to my user. I was trying to use criteria, but I think I'm missing something.

I also had a look here:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/A-Relationship-Paging-Pattern-td1326643.html

But then I would have to add the relation back into `UserRole` so I would have:

```
static hasMany = [users : UserRole]
```

How can I do this? what would be the best way?

Please, let me know if you need more information and sorry if I wasn't clear enough

Thanks and regards

Comment: Hi @BurtBeckwith, thanks for fixing the formatting :) and sorry about it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot paginate an "ordinary" relationship.

You can change the order child objects appear in using [mapping DSL](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/sort.html):

```
static mapping = {
    sort name:desc
}
```

To simplify a hand-crafted paginated relationship, you can use a named query:

```
class Role {
    static namedQueries = {
        userRoles {
            eq('user', UserSessionService.instance.currentUser)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can implement a transient `User`'s property that will return a `Criteria` for `User`'s `Role`s (which can be paginated).

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for your quick response. The app I'm working on is a CRUD app. So I have a master table with the existing users. When I select 1 user then I display the detail. In the detail I want to display a table with the roles associated to this user, among other things. Then I want to be able to sort against DB this roles table by different fields depending on the column header selected.And I want to paginate the results. isn't there a way to do this using criteria without having the relationship bidirectional?

Comment: Furthermore in my case I think I would have to add           static hasMany [users : User] to UserRole class if I want it to be bidirectional, and static belongsTo [User]

Comment: 1. You never have to make the relationship bidirectional. Just add `belongsTo` or `hasMany` on a needed side. 2. Pass an user `id` to a `listRoles` action, and don't forget to add the same `id` to `params` of `g:paginate` and `g:sortableColumn`. 3. Anyway, comments are too short for a complete sample.

Answer (score 0):

Grails Pagination with hasmany relation Bidirectional property finally i come to the point were i found it working Huuuh.

These are the Domain classes

```
class Client {
    List bills
    String shopName
    String nameOfClient
    static hasMany = [bills: Bill]

    static constraints = {
        shopName(blank:true, nullable:true)
        nameOfClient(blank:false, nullable:false)       

    }

}

class Bill {
    String billDetails
    String billNo    
    static belongsTo = [client: Client]

    static constraints = {
        billDetails(blank:true, nullable:true , type: 'text')       
        billNo(blank:true, nullable:true)

    }

}
```

Now This is my controller Logic

```
 def clientDetails(){
    def maxJobs = 4 
    def offset = (params?.offset) ?: 0
    def clientId = params.id
    def bills = Client.get(clientId).bills
    def client= Client.get(clientId)
    def results = Bill.withCriteria {
        eq('client', client)
        firstResult(offset as Integer)
        maxResults(maxJobs)
    }

    [id:client.id,bills: results, offset: offset, max: maxJobs, totalJobs:   bills.size()]
}
```

And the gsp code

```
 <g:each in="${bills}">
       <tr>
           <td>${it.billNo}</td>
           <td>${it.billDetails}</td>          
       </tr>
 </g:each>



<g:paginate class="pagination" controller="client" action="clientDetails" total="${totalJobs?:0}" offset="${offset}" max="${max}" params="[id:"${id}"]"
                prev="&laquo; Previous" next="Next &raquo;" />
```